# Value of line integral $\int_c \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx + \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy$ for a curve $c$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, line-integrals

I'm trying to find the value of $\int_c \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx + \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy$ along the curve $c(t) = (1+2cost,sint), 0\leq t\leq 2\pi$

I found the potential fuction $\phi = \tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$ $s.t.$
$\phi_x = \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}$  and $\phi_y = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$

Therefore, my answer is $\phi(x,y)]_{c(0)}^{c({2\pi})} = \phi(2,0) - \phi(2,0) = 0$. But the answer I checked was $2\pi$. What did I wrong in my solution?

Regards

Comment: You can't use the potential function like this since the curve contains a point $(0,0)$ which would destroy the function under the integral. Use the substitution instead: $x=x(t)=1+2\cos(t)$ and $y=\sin(t)$ then compute the expressions $dx$ and $dy$ in term of $dt$  and evaluate integrals for $0\le t \le 2\pi$. Try it?

Comment: Ok I  wll try the method you've suggested. Thank you. B.t.w. what is the exact meaning of "destroy the  function under the integral "? Did you mean "To use potential function the curve doesn't contain undefined point in its interior"?

Comment: "destroy the function under the integral " means that if substitute $x=y=0$ you will not get a defined value for the function next to $dx$ and $dy$ (there are actually two fucntions)

Comment: I should be more precide: not "the curve" contains ... "the area enclosed by the curve"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your potential function $\phi(x,y) = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$ is discontinuous on the line $x=0$, which $c$ crosses twice.  This is the reason your method failed.

To redeem it, we may break $c$ up into three parts: (1) $0 \leq t < 2\pi/3$, (2) $2\pi/3 < t < 4\pi/3$, and (3) $4\pi/3 < t \leq 2\pi$, and add up all the results, giving

$$\left(\lim_{x\to 0^+}\phi(x,\sqrt{3}/2) - \phi(2,0)\right) + \left(\lim_{x\to 0^-} \phi(x,-\sqrt{3}/2)-\lim_{x\to 0^-} \phi(x,\sqrt{3}/2)\right)+\left(\phi(2,0)-\lim_{x\to 0^+} \phi(x,-\sqrt{3}/2)\right) = \frac\pi2 + \pi + \frac\pi2 = 2\pi$$

---

If it helps, your initial attempt is similar to the one-variable error:
$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac1x\,dx \color{red}= \ln|x|\Big|_{-1}^1 = \ln|1| - \ln|-1| = 0$$
where again the problem is that the "potential" $\ln|x|$ is discontinuous at $x=0$.  The fix here is to split the interval at $x=0$ and evaluate as improper integrals.  Your problem has the same fix.

Comment: A slight warning: I'm using the fact that $\phi$ restricted to $x > 0, y>1$ may be extended continuously to $x\geq 0, y>1$ in order to simplify the results of breaking up the interval into three parts.  If $\phi$ weren't sufficiently well-behaved to let that happen, you'd need to take all the one-sided limits along $c$ instead, but here we need not do so.